# Accounts disappearing in Xcode 9

Tags: xcode, apple-id

[image]

I upgraded to Xcode 9.0 recently and for some reason my accounts doesn't get stored in the Accounts panel anymore. Xcode stores them if I close the program, but NOT when I restart the computer.

I guess this is a bug and not a new feature, but are there any hacks or settings that I could change to prevent my accounts from disappearing (except from never turn off the computer that is)?

Comment: I have all my accounts there in Xcode 9, upgraded from 8.

Comment: Mine shows all accounts. Try to reinstall. Maybe something went wrong while updating the application.

Comment: Xcode 9 has disappeared my accounts 4 times since I loaded it last week.

Comment: having same issue ... tried reinstalling `XCode` but didn't work :(

Comment: same issue in xcode 10. Any solution??

Answer (score 2):

For the ones who may concern I've experienced a quite similar bug. In my case, some accounts disappeared and some others just "loose" the authentication with a "please relogin message". Even if I re-insert the credentials they disappear every time I quit and reopen Xcode.

Inspecting Console.app, I noticed that the problem seems related to a "not signed" binary regarding Xcode internal tools:

```
com.apple.dt.Xcode.KeychainService (DVTFoundation)
Subsystem: -- Category: -- 

DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-14154/IDEFoundation/Provisioning/KeychainService/main.m:59
Details:  Connecting process is not Apple-signed (Error Domain=DVTSecErrorDomain Code=-67050 "code failed to satisfy specified code requirement(s)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=code failed to satisfy specified code requirement(s)})
Object:   <IDEKeychainServiceDelegate: 0x7f9e93404000>
Method:   -_shouldAcceptConnectionFromPID:error:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7f9e93403290>{number = 2, name = (null)}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
```

Reinstalling a complete clean macOS 10.13.4 and Xcode 9.3 was not helpfull. The problem was still there.

After struggling a lot with this bug, I found that after launching the previous version of Xcode 9.2 and  configured the AppleIDs on this version results in a working one even with Xcode 9.3. Now AppleIDs appear correctly configured and working without any issues.

Comment: Unbelievable! It worked for me! Just install and launch Xcode 9.2!

Comment: I could resolved this by setting user defaults. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53878066/2746582

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by reinstalling Xcode. Apparently something went wrong in the first upgrading process.

Before reinstallation I deleted the app in Applications folder and deleted everything in ~/Library/Caches folder.