# Xcode preferences -> accounts not saved

Tags: xcode10, ios12, apple-id

Generally in `Xcode` we can save different apple accounts in preferences.
It was working before in previously all versions.

Last week I have updated `Xcode` and installed `Xcode version 10.0`
And then I have added 3-4 Apple IDs :

> Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts

But next day when I open `Xcode`, all accounts are gone.

I have tried many times, but same thing happened everytime next day I found blank in

> Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts

Seems that `Xcode 10` can't keep apple accounts saved in preferences.

- What's the problem ?
- Is it Xcode bug ?
- Need to do any extra setup for this ?

[image]

Comment: What build number Xcode are you using? (it's shown in the Xcode/About Xcode panel)? In some earlier beta builds there were problems with accounts disappearing, it happened to me, but afaik that was fixed in later updates.

Comment: @ZoëSmith I have mentioned in question that `Xcode 10.0`

Comment: hello. did you fix this issue? I have same problem with Xcode 14.3.1

Answer (score 1):

Xcode uses Keychain Access Groups to store your Apple ID credentials in the keychain. I could fixed this problem by setting a user default.

First I deleted all accounts in Xcode and Xcode App, 
and then used below command in Terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode DVTDeveloperAccountUseKeychainService -bool NO
```

Finally, I installed Xcode app again.

Before deleting Xcode,  try to change a user default of DVTDeveloperAccountUseKeychainService.