# Xcode doesn't allow to keep two apple accounts in preferences

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-developer-account

I'm using Xcode 14.3.1 and it doesn't allow me to keep two apple accounts in preferences. But it was working before.

I've added 2 Apple IDs, let's say acc1 and acc2:

> Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts

But after few hours, only first account, acc1, remains in settings (and vice versa. If I add acc2 and then acc1, acc2 remains in settings). Xcode allows to keep only the first account.

I deleted and reinstalled Xcode few times, but problem remains.

Anyone faced with this problem and know how to fix this?

**note**:
I tried [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53878066/10834878), but the problem remains